# R mixed effects model with autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, and percentage data

Tags: r, mixed-model, autocorrelation

I'm would like to double check that my model properly accounts for correlation among years (sites were sampled each year) and heteroscedasticity (wedge shaped). The y-variable and X1 variables are percentages (#/total)....not binary. X2 is a covariate. I know how to handle each of these individually, though not all together.

I've been following Zurr's book. I am comparing several models and will use AIC for model selection criteria.

The only models that work thus far are `mod1` and `mod3`.

```
# v3 allows variance increasing with X1 and year
v3 <- varComb(varIdent(form =~ 1 | Year) , varExp(form =~ y ) )
#### random intercept model with variance increasing with X1 and year
mod1 <- lme(y ~ 1 + X1 + X2, random = ~ 1 |Site/Year, weights = v3)

### random interacept AND random slope model with variance increasing with X1 and year
mod2 <- lme(y ~ X1 + X2, random = ~ 1 + Year|Site, weights = v3)
```

With mod 2, I receive:

> nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
>     message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)

```
v2 <- varFixed(~ X2) # allows variance to increase with X only

#### random intercept model with variance increasing with X1 and year
mod3 <-  lme(y ~ 1 + X1 + X2, random = ~ 1 |Site/Year, weights = v2)
summary(mod3)

### random intercept AND random slope model with variance increasing with X1 only
mod4 <- lme(y ~ X1+ X2, random = ~ 1 + Year|Site, weights = v3)
```

With mod4, I receive this error message:

> In nlminb(c(coef(lmeSt)), function(lmePars) -logLik(lmeSt, lmePars),  :
>     NA/NaN function evaluation

Comment: It isn't clear if this is a 'check my code' question or a 'check my statistical methods' question. Please clarify. If you have multiple yes/no events, you do not want to model them as a %, but as a binomial. Generically, in `R`, that would be `glm(cbind(yeses, nos)~<stuff>, family=binomial)`.

Comment: it's more a please check that I have taken care of the random effects, autocorrelation, and a variance that increases with the mean properly.

Comment: the data are percentage female out of total....I'm more worried about the other parts of the model though. Thanks!